# Most efficient data structure for add and remove by key in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, system, python-dataclasses

I need to save a **dataclasses** object by one of its attributes `user_id`, and frequently query the `user_id` and delete it if the key exists. The `UserInfo` class is defined below:

```
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class UserInfo:
    user_id: int
    book: str
    bookshelf_color: str
    money: int
    size: int

# operation for this data structure D
if user_id in D:
   del D[user_id]
```

So far I can only think of using the built-in `dict()`(Or the Dict from typing in Python3) to store it: `user_id` as key, and `UserInfo` object as value. So deletion uses **del** keyword(Or **pop**? not sure which is better/Pythonic). But I was wondering if there's a more efficient solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to have a collection and query it by a key there isn't really a way to go about it that will be better than using a dict

Regarding del vs pop, since you say that the key will not always exist I would go with pop, but you can always use del and wrap it in try/except